# Static on opening MacBook Air when not plugged in

Tags: mac

I get static on opening my MacBook Air, even when it's not plugged in.  If I close it then and re-open, the static no longer appears.  I run my hand across the top first, which may do nothing.  I tried running my hand across the top before opening at all, and it didn't work; maybe it would if I waited longer before opening.  I had the laptop for over a year before any static appeared.

Answer (score 1):

If static electricity is building up on your laptop it sounds like a grounding issue with one of the wires perhaps, you may want to take it to someone who knows their way around macbooks to check as this could lead to further issues.